# Can i.i.d. random variables be negative?

Tags: random-variable, iid

I know that random variables can take negative values, so can independent and identically distributed random variables be negative?

Comment: Do you have a broader context in which you are asking the question? While I hope my answer is useful to you, many of the tags you’ve included do not seem particularly related to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Take any set of iid values that are non-negative.

For each one, put a minus sign in front of it. You now have a new set of i.i.d. variables that are negative.

Answer (score 1):

**YES**

Consider a distribution $D$ that takes either $-1$ or $-2$ with equal probability.

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n\overset{iid}{\sim}D$. Then the $X_i$ are $iid$ yet only take negative values.